# error en hosting web pero no en xampp al hacer una busqueda sql

Tags: sql, hosting

El error que me aparece es el siguiente

Error buscando Usuarios:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 7

En mi pc local xampp puedo ver la información guardada en la página visitada pero la página web no puedo.

Mi hosting es www.000webhost.com y uso la misma version de php en los 2 servidores (5.6) , lo que no se si hay versiones distintas de mysql que sean la causa del error

Mi búsqueda sql

```
function searchUser($conexion, $id){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              WHERE u.id = ".$id." ")) or die("Error buscando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Ya he intentado subir nuevamente el archivo sin éxito

Comment: hola @IgmerRodriguez por favor revisa lo remarcado en rojo en su pregunta ahi esta el error que le devuelve

Comment: xreo que te sobran las dos comillas ultimas .$id." "))